# Filter table with a slider in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, filter, slider

What I want to accomplish - The slider search function on this page: http://xn--norskeln-g0a.com/smalan/.

I'm using wordpress. And I have honestly no idea how I should make this work. Any tip etc. are extremely welcoming.

So, I want a table with different data and a slider to sort out data from that table and show only that data in the table. This is going to be used in almost the same way as on the page I linked to above.

Any ideas?

Comment: The table btw that i have looks like this - https://s31.postimg.org/wht7w1scr/Sk_rmklipp.png

And I want to filter on one or two columns with two differnt sliders

Comment: have you tried googling "javascript number slider"?